# Integrating Android .aar lib

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to integrate the cwac-cam2 library with codenameone. The lib is in .aar format but when I build it fails whith the following error:

org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I can not find out what is wrong. Can you help me please?

Lib reference: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit difficult for me to say what exactly wrong is, but you can try some general steps that I would follow like

1) Check your .aar lib is residing at appropriate location. Normally for Android it will be at `..\YourProject\native\android\YourLib.aar`
(also do 'Refresh cn1lib files' once, because I did so.. lol)

2) check build hint and make sure you have
`android.enableProguard = false`

3) If you are using any activity from that .aar lib then make sure you have added those activity/ies in build hint as `android.xapplication = <activity android:name="com.XX.YY.MyActivity" />`

I would further suggest you look at Chen's post on ARR integration here: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-android-3rd-party-libraries-jni.html

Also notice that gradle builds are often harder to work with in terms of result readability. I would suggest trying to disable gradle first and getting it to work without it then re-enabling it so you can test with android studio if necessary. You can disable gradle with the build hint `android.gradle=false`.

Comment: Added a couple of additional suggestions at the bottom

Comment: please provider some actual support how to do that. Integrating aar file is failing in you build server